# Delete unused files (parse-server)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I need to clean up my unused files from my parse-server. Now the "CleanUp files" button doesn't exist, how can I achieve this?

It's possible to delete all my files that are not used in any row?

Comment: What do you mean by unused? Those that are not the target of pointers?

Comment: @Marta  yes, those are not the target of any pointer.